# Standard deviation of a probability

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

If I have 4 numbers, let's say 0 1 1 1. I can say the average is 0.75, or 75%.  The standard deviation is 0.5. If I want to plot the percentage ( I have a series of data like this). I would have 75% plus or minus what percent would represent the standard deviation ?

Comment: @Creator what? more generally, how I can I should the error for these probabilities? If the probability of it happening is saying 75%, what is the error on this given the data above?

Answer (score 0):

When plotting it is more a matter of convention. Sometimes one puts error bars in terms of the standard deviation, sometimes it is the maximum range. It may even be done in terms of the euclidean norm or a certain multiple of standard deviations. It depends on what purpose you are making the graph. If you are going to plot lines of worst fit it is important to plot the maximum range of the error. If you are working on a manufacturing process that has to be six sigma compliant then you would plot six times the standard deviation. In most cases though it is a single standard deviation.